# How to execute events upon selecting a checkbox, radio button, etc

Tags: jquery, forms, radio-button

I'm trying to show a div upon selecting a checkbox or radio button. I'm not using the click function or anything complicated. Can anyone find my problem in my code? It should be a breeze to solve. Thanks!

```js
$(() => {
  if ($("input#checkbox").is(':checked')) {
    $('#add-a-car').show();
    // Code in the case checkbox is checked.
  } else {
    $('#add-a-car').hide();
    // Code in the case checkbox is NOT checked.
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="add-a-car">Add-a-Car</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox">
<div id="add-a-car">
  <label for="add-a-car">Pick your date</label>
  <input type="text" value="pick-a-date">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To do what you require you need to use an event handler. In this case the `change` event, which fires when the `checked` state of the radio is changed. Also note that you can simplify the logic slightly by using the `toggle()` method.

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $('#checkbox').on('change', e => {
    $('#add-a-car').toggle(this.checked);
  });
});
```

```css
#add-a-car { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="add-a-car">Add-a-Car</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox">
<div id="add-a-car">
  <label for="add-a-car">Pick your date</label>
  <input type="text" value="pick-a-date">
</div>
```

Comment: Is the change method the only method to use? Can I use .is(:selected)? The code looks good. Thanks a million.

Comment: You will have to use an event handler, yes, and `change` is by far the most appropriate to use here. Just using `is()` as the code in your question does means it only runs when the page loads, not when the user interacts with any of the controls on the page.

Comment: Thanks Rory! I appreciate all your input.